# Открыть файл ехе на андройд планшете

Tags: android, exe

Android 11, есть некий файл Setup.exe он небольшого размера но никак не мог его открыть принудительно. Сначала попробовал с помощью ЕХ Проводника и соответственно eltechs.es,но не вышло, просто не открывается, я его скачал но не могу открыть выдаёт ошибку "не найдена иллюстрация приложения, попробуйте переустановить". Я скачал его в .obb и закинул в папку приложения через EX Проводник, вроде по гайдам должно работать а нет, вобщем забил. Полез в старющий эмулятор Bochs который не поддерживало моё устройство но я все равно его запустил. Значит сделал все по инструкции, создал папку перенёс туда нужный файл Setup.exe, запускаю и меня выбивает из программы, ищу проверять что случилось, запускаю из вне, никак "невозможно воспроизвести". Кароче устал я, если есть у кого идеи буду рад

Comment: .exe файл это для Windows, он не запустится на Android. Это несовместимые операционные системы. Android больше похож на Linux, чем на Windows.